# is it possible to make NFC tag read protected in android?

Tags: android, nfc

How to make NFC tag read protected without use of any encryption in android so that no one can read data from that tag??is it possible or not??

Comment: What's the purpose of a tag that nobody can read? It's equivalent to physically destroy it.

Comment: Only owner can read it thats the purppose i mean from one single application only we can read

Comment: Instead of that you may add encrypted info to NFC tag only owner will understand the meaning. For others it would be junk data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to protect a tag so that it can only be read by a phone/reader with the correct password. However only certain tags have this ability. I have worked with some STMicro tags which have password protection, see: http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM76/CL1766/SC1204 and http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM76/CL1766/SC1412.

This answer by [NFC guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202968/nfc-guy) also lists some other tags which have this feature: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15703394/3312868